# Transpile Node script for testing

Tags: node.js, import, babeljs, es6-modules, transpiler

I have some es6 modules I would like to unit test in node.  Renaming all the files to .mjs is not a workable option.

For simplicity, let's say I have a file like this `mymodule.js` that has these contents:

```
export default {
  saySomething: function () { console.log("something"); }
}
```

And I want to write a simple script to test it like this `test.js` with these contents:

```
import { saySomething } from './mymodule';
saySomething();
```

I'm really not looking to learn Babel at this point.  I just need some simple, clear instruction like:

- Create a .babelrc that contains `<blahblah>`
- install such-and-such
- then run `npx babel test.js` (or whatever)

I searched around and kept finding a bunch of long tutorials about loading babel modules and what not.

I'm just looking for an expedient recipe--an incantation--not an explanation.  Surely that's available somewhere; I just can't find it.  any help?

**Update**

A reply below says no transpilation is necessary because node understands ES6 automatically.  I'm willing that I'm just misunderstanding, but when I run this exact example using Node v11.12.0, I get the following error:

```
$ node test.js

/home/usr/test/test.js:1
import { saySomething } from './mymodule';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're misunderstanding something here. ES6 code that you want to execute in node.js does not need to be babel-transpiled at all. Node natively understands ES6. You'd only have to transpile it if you wanted to run it in a browser.

Comment: Maybe I am; I'm willing.  But if I use the exact example I posted (using node v11.12.0) I get the error:  ... import { saySomething } from './mymodule';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:23) ...  Updating the post to say the same.

Comment: Damnit! You're right. Node does indeed not support the import/export syntax yet. :-(